Setting up Turbo stream broadcasts_refreshes, websocket error
I'm trying to configure a Rails 7.1.3/Turbo 2.0.5 app locally to try out broadcasts_refreshes for a simple model. On the view template that tries to turbo_stream_from this model, I'm getting websocket errors, indicating that it is trying to connect.
Here are the errors I am getting:
# in the browser, with or without the above config.action_cable.url
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: There was a bad response from the server.

# in the terminal window, while rails server is running
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2024-04-18 01:14:20 -0700
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2024-04-18 01:14:20 -0700
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
WebSocket error occurred: undefined method `write_nonblock' for nil
::1 - - [18/Apr/2024:01:14:20 PDT] "GET /cable HTTP/1.1" -1 0
WebSocket error occurred: undefined method `write_nonblock' for nil

Main questions:

Do the above error messages mean the authentication didn't pass?

If Turbo creates its own channels, does it also create its own websocket connections and handle its own auth logic separately? Or does it use my app's ActionCable connection authentication logic in the app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb file? (My connection.rb file is currently empty, because we don't use ActionCable for anything else.)

Does Rails start the redis server for ActionCable automatically with rails s?


What I tried that doesn't seem to work:

Add to routes.rb:

mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"


Add to config/environments/development.rb:

config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/,/https:\/\/*/]

App configuration:

gem turbo-rails version 2.0.5
gem redis installed. I have run ./bin/rails turbo:install:redis
cable.yml configured for redis in development, thanks to this answer.

development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1


model declares broadcasts_refreshes

class FieldSlip < ApplicationRecord
  broadcasts_refreshes


view template has turbo_stream_from:

<%= turbo_stream_from(:field_slip, dom_id(field_slip)) %>
<%= render(partial: "field_slips/row",
           locals: { field_slip: field_slip }) %>

Everything on the template side seems to be working, Turbo is generating turbo-cable-stream-source tags, but I notice there is no connected attribute:
<turbo-cable-stream-source channel="Turbo::StreamsChannel" signed-stream-name="ImZpZWxkX3NsaXBfam9iX3RyYWNrZXI6ZmllbGRfc2xpcF9qb2JfdHJhY2tlcl8xIg==--bcf536df9f893f646adb2ce946d4d8ffa166eb297cca1a5c7fa093c77b0da878"></turbo-cable-stream-source>

Clearly, the websocket is not working. What am I missing?

Not dived into the fresh Turbo stuff such as broadcasts_refreshes yet, but I can answer a few questions: 2) Turbo deals with websockets on its own. I used to broadcast in my app and my channels folder is basically untouched. connection.rb is empty and it worked perfectly fine. 3) Redis is not a server. It is a key value database that needs to exist on your server or local development computer. It is basically a binary to install independently from anything Rails related. Make sure you have it installed. In Ubuntu just type redis-server -v to print the version of Redis.

Also Redis is usually demonized, it starts automatically at the boot of your system. In Linux, it is just a SystemD service. Also my environment doesn't show anything related to ActionCable. such as config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable" config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/,/https:\/\/*/] I guess Rails can find that by itself.

So in your cable.yml, are you using the async adapter for development?

Nope I am using redis as adapter. looks like this (in yml) : development: adapter: redis url: redis://localhost:6379 db: 4 I have also a redis.yml file which kinda duplicates what is in cable.yml and that I use for Sidekiq configuration

In my case it was the authentication issue. It is true that Turbo can connect to the websocket without authentication, but if your app requires authentication at that point, the websocket request needs authentication too. In our case, the whole view where the live updates should occur requires login.
Adjusting app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb to use the app's authentication logic (from the cookie) made it so the Action Cable request was authenticated the same way.
With this working, the turbo-cable-stream-source tag in the rendered page shows a connected attribute.

I also had the same issue. I noticed that not only did it affect the streams, but any Hotwire feature. I also tried all  the things you outlined.
What solved it for me was adding the following tag to the head in my application.html.erb:
<%= turbo_include_tags %>

Thanks for sharing what worked for you. Fwiw it seems this is deprecated in favor of javascript_include_tag "turbo", type: "module-shim" (or just "module" without importmaps).

If you're using importmap-rails and you have turbo pinned, and you have javascript_importmap_tags in your document head, you don't need to import turbo separately.
